# Get text from file Docx (wpf C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, document

i've been writing program to display text from .docx file (Also from PDF format). I want the program can read only text then show it to somewhere maybe textbox or whatever. What can i do ? or anyone has another way sugession for my work.This program is for 3 reporters read a news within one moniter and control their text by touch
                                                             Thanks everyone who answer me
                                                                            James K.

Comment: What is so common in Getting Text file from docx and WPF ?

Comment: So are you asking about reading from a docx file or displaying text using a touch interface?

Comment: i'm asking both of them, reading from docx to display it in touch interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into [this Docx library for .NET](http://docx.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks, GAP. I found how to write Docx file from your link but i cant see how to read text from Docx. I see a little bit of Docx class that it has a function to read but I dont know how to use it. Is there any example of it ? how can i find it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some nice solutions for converting a DOCX file to a string.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20529/Using-DocxToText-to-Extract-Text-from-DOCX-Files
http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/Content.aspx?id=5633

I hope it helps.
Regards